# Can a forward declared struct be used in a struct definition in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl

Can a struct that was forward declared be used in another struct's definition? For example:

```
struct  A;
struct B
{
     float x;
     float y;
     A     z;
};
```

I'm trying to parse GLSL files at link/compile time to make their use in C a lot easier. I can't seem to find details like this anywhere.

Comment: You can't declare objects of incomplete type. And this code doesn't compile.

Comment: Okay, so in that regard it's the same as C. So, no?

Comment: Ahh, didn't see the C++-tag, sorry. In C, that's impossible (besides the fact that you had to write `struct A z;`, but it still wouldn't compile), for C++, I think it's the same, but I'm not sure. Is this really a C-question (remove the tag otherwise)?

Comment: It's GLSL like it says in the title. Neither C nor C++.

Comment: @Ben I removed the 'c' and 'C++' tags, since they obviously caused confusion.

Comment: For what it worth a similar code compile on my machine (NVIDIA latest driver)

Comment: @cifz Where was the struct defined?

Comment: Same as your code before the main function. I've also tried to use it (defining something in A) as follow (note that this is extremely dummy as code, just to see if compiles): [click](https://gist.github.com/CifaCia/f0b3d3cf3e65fcc912cb). Unfortunately I don't have time to check further so don't take my words as an 100% confirm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, forward declared structures are not officially supported in GLSL. [The spec, section 4.1.8](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf) on structures does not mention such feature, and reading the grammar appendix, I couldn't find any mentions either.

If you think about it, forward declarations are not really useful in GLSL as they are in C. Since GLSL doesn't have pointers, trying to use a forward declared struct would be trying to access an incomplete type. In C, forward declarations serve de purpose of allowing the declaration of opaque pointers.

If you are writing a custom parser for GLSL, make sure to read section 9 of the [GLSL spec](https://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/GLSLangSpec.Full.1.20.8.pdf): *Shading Language Grammar*. GLSL is based on C, but it is only a very small subset of C.